# Excel IFfunction only works when true otherwise returns #VALUE

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Here is my formula `=IF(FIND("MB",E809),"MB","KB")`

I have also tried `=IF(FIND("MB",E809),1,1024)`

I'm just testing if the cell has `KB` or `MB`. The cell I'm currently testing has `424.89 KB` as the data.  If I change the data to have `MB` rather than `KB`, then the formula will return either `MB` or `1`. The formula works fine if it is true, but always seems to fail when it gets to the [value if false] portion of the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FIND` returns #VALUE if the string is not found.

You probably want `=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("MB",E809)),"MB","KB")`